# How to change default cache policy in Okhttp?

Tags: android, http, picasso, okhttp

I am using Picasso for image loading. Picasso doesn't have a disk cache. OkHttp maintains an HTTP cache that is controlled by HTTP cache headers. I want to set an expiry for disk cached images so added cache-control headers in HTTP response `cache-control: public, max-age=7200` but it is not respecting cache headers. The current behavior is the default HTTPResponseCache which honors RFC 7234.
Is there anything we are missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite cache headers in the response with a network interceptor. Here's an example from the [OkHttp interceptors doc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/#rewriting-responses) to get you started:

```
/** Dangerous interceptor that rewrites the server's cache-control header. */
private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
  @Override public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
    return originalResponse.newBuilder()
        .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=60")
        .build();
  }
};
```

Note that you might need to remove headers from the server's response to get your desired caching behavior.

Note also that it's strictly better to fix the server to do what you want; that way it'll work correctly on iOS and on the web.

Comment: We tried setting headers from client-side but still, it is not respecting `Cache-Control` headers. Is there any way to tell okhttp to cache these many hours?